# How to conditionally load a javascript or css?

Tags: 6, javascript

I just got assigned to a project that requires bug fixes. It is not a bug, but the client is asking us to reduce size of our site's compressed javascript.

I found out that the compressed js' size is around 500kb, which is pretty big. I think it is that big because Drupal loads all the javascript from all the enabled modules. The problem is that there are scripts that I don't use on my homepage or other pages.

What would be a good solution or workaround for my issue? One thing I can think of is to turn off compreconditionally disable modules in my template...but...is that okay or even possible?

Comment: Check this link: http://shvetsgroup.com/blog/optimizing-javascript-and-css-files-drupal . Don't try to remove default libraries like jquery etc. Also the I assume your web server is setting the expires headers then those javascript libraries will be loaded only once.

Comment: @Aga // thank you for the link and time to put your post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking to do is remove extra JS or CSS files, correct? [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) can do this for you.
hook_advagg_js_pre_alter()
hook_advagg_css_pre_alter()
are the hooks you want to implement. Then inside of the hook you can use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) function to figure out what page your on.

```
$args = arg();
if (   isset($args[0]) && $args[0] == 'node'
    && isset($args[1]) && is_numeric($args[1])
    && !isset($args[2])
      ) {
  $node = node_load($args[1]);
  if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'page') {
    // Do awesome stuff to the JS/CSS array.
  }
}
```

See [advagg_js_cdn_advagg_js_pre_alter()](http://drupalcode.org/project/advagg.git/blob/0fe046a6644711888e02e060fc13b3fda058a0fc:/advagg_js_cdn/advagg_js_cdn.module#l23) for an example on how the hook is used. Also be aware of [drupal_is_front_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/6); it might be useful.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out a [context add assets](http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets) module:

> This module will add a reaction within context to add theme, module,
>   or custom folder files to your page(s).
>
> Ever wanted to quickly add a css file to a theme? Include a js file on
>   only one page (or section?)
>
> Make using multiple CSS files a breeze with this module and harness
>   the power of Context in your theme!

From [context add assets](http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets) project page. Of course it requires the [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) and that maybe a lot of overhead to do something like this. But it's a lot easier!